# How to create a time series with a NetCDF raster from Ensembles E-OBS using GDAL, R, GRASS GIS or SAGA GIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, r, saga

I downloaded a NetCDF file that contains daily precipitation values from 1-1-1950 to 30-6-2013. The raster has 23191 bands.

http://eca.knmi.nl/download/ensembles/download.php

My goal is to analyze how precipitation values varied and relate the changes with the conservation of a forest ecosystem.

I'm unsure on how to proceed, but I think the first step should be to create a time series from the NetCDF raster.

How can I do this using GDAL, GRASS GIS or R?

Comment: In R, start with  library(raster);(ncdata <- brick("file.nc")) and report back on what you get. You'll need either ncdf4 or ncdf packages also installed for raster to use.

Comment: Thanks @mdsumner. After giving up on GDAL, started looking for solutions in R and found them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to myself. Using R and package "rts" it is possible to create a time series:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf)
library(stringr)
library(rts)


stack<-stack("pp_0.25deg_reg_v9.0.nc") #Create raster stack


datas<-c()
for (i in 1:length(stack@layers)) {
  word<-str_sub(as.character(stack@layers[[i]]@data@names), start=2, end=11L)
  word<-as.Date(format(as.Date(word,"%Y.%m.%d"),"%Y-%m-%d"))
  datas[[length(datas)+1]] <- word
} ##extract the strings with the dates and format them according to as.Date() requirements

as.Date(datas)->datas
rt <- rts(stack,datas) #Create raster stack time series

apply.yearly(rt, mean)->y # calculate the mean (annual) precipitation value
```

For additional information go to:

http://r-gis.net/?q=rts

Answer (score 1):

You may want to enjoy the new temporal GIS framework in GRASS GIS 7:

- GRASS as Temporal GIS presentation PDF
- A temporal GIS for field based environmental modeling ([article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S136481521300282X))
- Manual pages: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/temporalintro.html

An initial release of GRASS GIS 7 has been done two days ago at the Vienna OSGeo Code sprint: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.0.0beta-News

Time series aggregation, algebra and much more are now provided.

The examples in the aforementioned presentations are based on ECA&D.